# SQL Availability Group Failover Automation through PowerShell - Slow response

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to automate the process of failing over AGs on SQL Server 2017 and I run the below command remotely through PowerShell over remoting (port 5985)

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\INSTANCE01 -Query "ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP AG1 FAILOVER;"
The AG is the backend to a time sensitive financial application. What we are noticing is that when the AG is failed over manually through SQL Server Management Studio, it takes less than 10 seconds worth of blip in financial transactions where as when I do it through PowerShell it can take up to 75 seconds.

Please note, the SQL command above returns in under 10 seconds but the transactions team tell me there was blip of at east 70 seconds. That makes me think there is something missing in the failover SQL query above than what happens when done manually via SSMS.

So just wanted to know your thoughts as to what could be slowing things down. Thanks.

Comment: I'd check the AlwaysOn_Health session on both nodes (i.e. the former and current primary). While the failover itself might only take a couple of seconds, there are things like crash recovery that need to happen. That should all be logged in the aforementioned session. Also, just to rule it out, are both nodes in the same subnet? If not, are you running a multsubnet AG listener?

Comment: Thanks Ben. It looks like the failover in my automation was targeting the cross site node hence the issue. We are testing further.